# TextBox formatting with decimals

Tags: c#, winforms, decimal

I have a textBox in a winform that will be used to calculate Money values.

The behavior I want is such:

on load:

0,00

If i write something it should substitute from right to left...

So,if I would to display 100

I should type 1 0 0 0 0

in order to textBox progressively show:

```
0,01 
0,10 
1,00 
10,00 
100,00
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried?  There are numerous articles on formatting the display of decimals (and other things) in .NET.

Comment: I can display decimals using textBox1.Text = totalm.ToString("0.00"); but the behaviour I want is the same as a calculator would have. Substituting 0's from right to left on adding numbers and the reverse when deleting.

Comment: Put on hold for too broad!? The heck this is the simplest to understand!

Comment: Use `NumericUpDown` control instead of `TextBox`.

Comment: He did ask for a specific functionality the NumericUpDown cant give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. This does not support numPad inputs, do you want that?

```
string valueText = ""; // The sequence of numbers you've entered. Ex. 1 0 0 0 0

// This ensures that the textbox allways shows something like "0,00"
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string inputText = ""; // The text to print in textbox
    if (valueText.Length < 3) // If there are under 3 numbers in the number you've entered, add zeros before the number. Ex. if you've entered: 1 0 , then the box should print "0,10". Therefore, add the zeros if the value text's length is below 3
    {
        for (int zeros = 0; zeros < 3 - valueText.Length; zeros++)
            inputText += "0";
    }

    inputText += valueText; // Append the numbers you've entered

    textBox1.Text = inputText.Insert(inputText.Length - 2, ","); // insert the comma two positions from the right end
}

private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    List<Keys> keys = new List<Keys>() { Keys.D1, Keys.D2, Keys.D3, Keys.D4, Keys.D5, Keys.D6, Keys.D7, Keys.D8, Keys.D9, Keys.D0 }; // The keys you can press to enter a number

    if (keys.Contains(e.KeyCode)) // If the key you pressed is "accepted"
    {
        valueText += e.KeyCode.ToString().Replace("D", ""); // the key "1" will be "D1", therefore, remove the "D"
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back) // If backspace is pressed
    {
        if (valueText.Length > 0)
            valueText = valueText.Remove(valueText.Length - 1, 1); // Remove the last number Ex. 1,00 + backspace = 0,10
    }

    textBox1_TextChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty); // Update the text in the textBox
}
```

I hope this helps.

Edit: Remember to call `textBox1_TextChanged` on startup, or else the textbox will be blank

Comment: Using your solution did not provide the expect behaviour.

But it helped me to make this code:

`   if (textBox1.Text.Length > 3 && textBox1.Text.Contains(",") == false)
                {
                     textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(textBox1.Text.Length - 2, ","); // insert the comma two positions from the right end   
                }
                else  if (textBox1.Text.Length > 3 && textBox1.Text.Contains(",") == true)
                {
                    
                    
                }

                else
                { }`

Comment: Did you make sure to hook the two function onto the textbox's TextChanged and KeyDown Event?

Comment: Yes... The best it did, was to Always show 0,00. Using the code I showed you, I can add comma is there is none, but if I add more numbers, the comma doesn't move to the -2 position. If I change the else if to delete comme if there is any and add to -2 pos, it loops infinitely. Working on that. IF there were a way to check if the comma is into the -2 pos and if yes or no do stuff, but I don't know how to check for it.

Comment: Are you completely sure? I tested it myself and pressing 1 0 0 0 0 for me resulted in your example 0,01 
0,10 
1,00 
10,00 
100,00. textbox.KeyDown and textbox.textChanged under events, right?

Comment: Must have done something wrong before. Did as you said and worked 100%. Sorry for trouble you, my mistake.

Thanks a LOT!

PS: How can I enable num pad.

Comment: No prob! I wouldn't post anything before testing it :D Glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

Create an event handler that intercepts the text input and format it as you want:

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double value = 0;
    if(double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value))
        value /= 100.0;
    textBox.Text = String.Format("{0:f2}", value);
}
```

You may also need to limit what characters the user can insert into the text box:

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyPress(e);

    // let digits and . go
    if(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == '.'))
        return;

    // all other chars are ignored,
    // you can add other stuff here if needed like
    // the minus sign, backspace etc
    e.Handled = true;
}
```